# Conditional Gaussian Distribution

Tags: self-study, bayesian, normal-distribution, linear-algebra

I am trying to study [this paper](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/papers/NC110201.pdf) on Linear Gaussian Models.

I'm a little stuck on the following result for finding the conditional of a Gaussian:

[image]

In the paper it states this is done 'simply by linear matrix projection', could anyone possibly provide me with a starting point or some hints so I can try and understand how this is arrived at?